Wie lautet die standardisierte Aussprache von "schiefer" (Steigerungsform des Adjektivs "schief")?
Wird es als "schieFer" oder "schieWer" ausgesprochen?
Die Antwort kann auch auf ähnliche Wörter ausgeweitet werden.

Warum sollte ein f wie ein w gesprochen werden?

@Olafant Im Dialekt könnte es sein, dass das folgende e den Konsonanten erweicht.

@JonathanHerrera: In welchen Dialekten wäre das der Fall? Kannst du Beispiele nennen?

@HubertSchölnast Im Rheinischen wird es eher als "Schiewer" gesprochen. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rheinischer_Regiolekt#Aussprache ("In einigen Wörtern ist das rheinische [v] erhalten, besonders wo diesem im Hochdeutschen [f] entspricht, so z. B. oft dürven statt „dürfen“, .......)

@HubertSchölnast Da wo ich herkommen tu, klingt es mir ooch fast ä bisl wie schiewer. :)

Wann immer man sich schriftlich über die Aussprache von Wörtern unterhält, sollte man die Aussprache in IPA-Symbolen angeben. Diese Symbole sind wie Buchstaben, habe aber fixe und eindeutige Lautzuordnungen. Der Wikipedia-Artikel https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_der_IPA-Zeichen bietet eine vollständige Übersicht über diese Symbole. Sie enthält auch anklickbare Hörbeispiele.

Im Deutschen werden der einfache Buchstabe »f« (z.B. in »Ofen«) und der Doppelbuchstabe »ff« (z.B. in »offen«) immer mit dem Laut [f] ausgesprochen (Ofen = [ˈoːfn̩], offen = [ˈɔfn̩]). Es gibt im Deutschen keine anderen Laute, die den Buchstabenfolgen »f« und »ff« zugeordnet sind.

Der Laut [v], der z.B. am Anfang des Wortes »wo« erklingt (»wo« = [voː]) ist in keinem einzigen deutschen Wort dem Buchstaben »f« zugeordnet, sondern nur den beiden Buchstaben »w« (in jedem Wort, das den Buchstaben »w« enthält) und »v« (nur in Ausnahmefällen, z.B. »Vase« = [ˈvaːzə], »Klavier« = [klaˈviːɐ̯]) (Der Buchstabe »v« wird sonst mit dem Konsonanten [f] ausgesprochen: Vater = [ˈfaːtɐ]; vier =  [fiːɐ̯])

Wiktionary hat nicht nur für die Grundform jedes deutschen Worts einen Eintrag, sondern auch für jede grammatische Form. Daher gibt es dort auch einen Eintrag für das Wort »schiefer«.
Bei jedem Eintrag in Wiktionary ist auch die Aussprache in IPA-Lautschrift angegeben. Für das Wort »schiefer« lautet sie: [ˈʃiːfɐ]. Viele Wiktionary-Seiten haben auch Hörbeispiele für das jeweilige Wort, und das ist auch beim Wort »schiefer« der Fall.



+1  für die gute Didaktik.

Vielleicht bist du verwirrt von den Wörtern, die mit "f" geschrieben, aber mit /v/ ausgesprochen werden? (doof, Fünfer, Elfer, Zwölfer)
Standarddeutsch hat keine Erbwörter, die auf /v/ enden. Alle Wörter auf /v/ sind Fremdwörter, z.B. "brav", "aktiv" etc.
Die Wörter, die z.B. im Ripuarischen, Niederländischen und Englischen ein /v/ haben, haben im Standarddeutschen in der Regel ein /b/ oder /f/: Vergleiche "leben" mit "levve", "leven" und "live" oder "Ofen" mit "Ovve", "oven" und "oven".
Manche Sprecher haben daher an einigen Stellen /v/, wo der Standard* /f/ hat. Im Standard ist es aber immer /f/, bis auf wenige Ausnahmen:
Die erste ist "doof": "Doof" ist eine ziemlich doofe Art, "doof" zu schreiben. Denn "doof" kommt vom Niederdeutschen "dov" und mit "taub" verwandt. Für die meisten Sprecher endet "doof" wie im Niederdeutschen auf /v/, es "dov" zu schreiben wäre besser.
Die Zahlen "Fünfer", "Elfer" und "Zwölfer": Hier hat sich die Aussprache, beeinflusst von den Dialekten mit /v/ im Norden durchgesetzt, vor allem da es sich um umgangsprachliche Wörter handelt. Im Süden werden sie mit /f/ ausgesprochen.
Um deine Frage zu beantworten: "schiefer" hat /f/.
*: Ich weiß, dass es den Standard so nicht gibt. Ich meine natürlich, dass niemand behaupten würde, "Ofen" mit /v/ wäre korrekt und ein erstrebenswerter Standard.

Wiktionary gibt für 'doof' die Aussprache [doːf] an, und das entspricht auch der mir geläufigen Aussprache.

@RHa: Lies genauer: Im englischen Wiktionary steht [do:v-] (inflected forms) und im Deutschen steht " Daher auch die Aussprache der flektierten Formen und des Komparativs und Superlativs mit [v] entsprechend der plattdeutschen Aussprache." /v/ wird am Ende /f/ ausgesprochen wegen Auslautverhärtung. Aktiv wird ja auch [ak'ti:f] ausgesprochen.
